# Array in method - JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse

I saw this code in one of the tutorials.
There isn't any error with it, but I just don't understand the code.
Could someone guide me?

```
int trying[] = {3,4,5,6,7};
change (trying);

for(int y: trying) {
    System.out.println(y);
    }
}
public static void change (int x[]) {
    for ( int counter = 0; counter < x.length ; counter++){
        x[counter] += 5;
     }
}
```

Able to explain this part for me?

```
for(int y: trying) {
    System.out.println(y);
 }
```

I don't understand especially this line of code:

> for (int y : trying)

Comment: that means: `for each int contained in "trying" array, set this int as "y" and execute following block`

Answer (score 5):

**Java for-Each loop Syntax:**

```
for(data_type variable : array | collection){}
```

**Advantage**:

- It makes the code more readable.

in your example

```
 for(int y: trying){
     System.out.println(y);
 }
```

simply means like int **y** will iterate over all the values in **trying**. Like,

```
for(int i=0;i < trying.length;i++){
      int y = trying[i]; 
      System.out.println(y);
}
```

Collection:

```
 List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // add "monkey", "donkey", "skeleton key" to someList

    for (String item : someList) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
```

same as:

```
 for (Iterator<String> itr = someList.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
       String item = itr.next();
       System.out.println(item);
    }
```

as it discussed earlier in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Comment: `for(int y=0;y < trying.length;y++)` in your answer would mean that it would print values from 0 to `trying.length`

Comment: yes but the output is the content of the array `trying`

Comment: Ok, But what about the code in the question?

Comment: You could also provide an example of what happens in case of collections.

Comment: I am sorry if I offended you. I was just trying to draw your attention to the problem in your answer. Now it seems OK to me.

Answer (score 2):

It's a for-each loop, a convenient way to loop over an array, a `Collection`, or more generally any `Iterable`.

For example, looping over an array of integers `int[] trying`, you can do:

```
for(int i=0; i<trying.length; i++) {
  int y = trying[i];
  // stuff with y
}
```

or using a `while`, an iterator... But this is a bunch of character, we are lazy and our fingers are tired. So here is shorter way to do such frequent operation:

```
for( int y : trying ) {
  // stuff with y
}
```

Behind the hood, the extended for cache an `Iterator` for any `Iterable`, or the index for an array, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) is the JLS specification.

Comment: Here's the documentation for it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html

Comment: here is question is about an `int` array and not a `Collection`

Comment: @Blip Well, I think this is more a question about for-each than a question about array, but you're right, I'm going to change my example :)

Comment: no it does not use iterator for an array. refer to link provided by DJClaywort. also refer to my answer where I have quoted from this document.

Answer (score 2):

`for(int y: trying)` is an implementation of `foreach` loop in java. This can be understood as:

```
for(int i = 0; i< trying.length; i ++){
    int y = trying[i];
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) states

> The for-each construct is also applicable to arrays, where it hides
>   the index variable rather than the iterator.

Comment: +1, since this makes more sense, then the answer with two upvotes. `int y` is the value contained in each array index, not the value of the index, as specified in that answer by @Hiru

Comment: For a simple and light description [PLUS ONE]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so trying[] is an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) of integers. The function change() takes trying[] as input and +5 to every integer in trying[]. And the [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) that you are asking about is just syntactic sugar that can shorten code.

Look at the doc links and try running it in eclipse or some IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i can give you the information want or need.

Int `trying[]` is an array of integer.

with the for loop you loop trough the `trying[]` array, and everytime you circle trough you send a message to the console.

Then you have your second loop

so if you int counter is smaller then the length of the array x[] then you keep circling trough the loop. as soon as the counter reaches the same length or value as the x[] then the loop stops.

```
for(int y: trying) {
    System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

So the example above isnt  really that hard, the loop will continue to the point where i is greater or the same as trying.

with this information you can figure out the last for loop by yourself:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 1):

This is called a foreach loop. So in words it says:

For each item "y" in the array "trying" - do something (here: print it).

It is very convenient in the case you don't care how often you loop but just want to address every item in the array/collection.

Alternatively you could just use the "normal" for loop as you used it in the change method.

Answer (score 1):

It says,
run the code in { ... } for each object in trying.

Datatype is int, because trying is an array of int.

"y" is a variable that holds an object from trying (one at a time).

For example,
when looping first time, y gets first value (3) from the array and runs the code between { and }. Then, y gets second value (4) from the array and run the same code again....and so on.

In this case, it will print a value of y for each object in trying.

```
for(int y: trying)
{
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

Datatype mentioned in for loop must be the same as the type of array.
for Example,

```
for (String s : allLines) { ... }
for (Member m : allMembers) { ... }
```